# SQL - foreign key referencing a view

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

Dunno how to implement following, please help:

Suppose, there are following tables:

```
create table dc_cities
(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  description varchar(100)
);
create table dc_languages
(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  description varchar(100)
);
create table people
(
  name varchar(100),
  surname varchar(100),
  city integer not null references dc_cities(id),
  language integer not null references dc_languages(id)
);
```

And I'd like to combine both these dc_ tables into single one (including any other of that kind then):

```
create table dc_dict
(
  dc_id integer not null,
  id integer not null,
  primary key(dc_id, id),
  name varchar(100),
  description varchar(100)
);
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(1, 1, 'City 1');
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(1, 2, 'City 2');
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(1, 3, 'City 3');
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(2, 1, 'Language 1');
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(2, 2, 'Language 2');
insert into dc_dict(dc_id, id, name) values(2, 3, 'Language 3');
```

The question is, how to describe/create a foreign key/reference in that case? Sure, it's possible to add a column for each referenced data set, for example like that:

```
create table people
(
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  surname varchar(100),

  city_dict_id integer not null check(city_dict_id=1) default 1,
  city integer not null,
  foreign key(city_dict_id, city) references dc_dict(dc_id, id),

  language_dict_id integer not null check(language_dict_id=2) default 2,
  language integer not null,
  foreign key(language_dict_id, language) references dc_dict(dc_id, id)
);
```

But it's unclear and require additional space etc.
I need a portable solution, so I cannot use 'virtual' columns, as they have different syntax or even not supported (in PostgreSQL for example). Also, it is not possible to use foreign key to the view or to use a constant in the foreign key declaration.
Surely, it can be done using triggers, but it's not transparent and I'd like not to mix declaration with the functionality.
Please share your experience - is there a right and elegant  way to implement that?

Thank you.

Comment: Foreign keys can never reference a view, they always reference a table (and its primary key)

Comment: Thank you, Captain 
That's why I'm asking this question. I thought I described the problem well - I need something that will do the trick like "foreign key to the view" but without it.

Comment: It appears to me that person->{city->country} is a hierarchical relation.(google: 3NF: transitive dependency)

Comment: Does not matter, it's just an example to illustrate the question. Let it be city and language, whatever. The question is, how to reference such a table.

Comment: It would solve your *problem*(which is an artifact caused by the bad modelling, IMHO)

Comment: Why 'bad'? It could be very handy to use such a design, for example for automatic frontends generation or scripting, etc. And, surely, it's much better than current situation, when our system has about 200 'dc_' tables with the same structure.

Well, maybe I'm wrong and you could advice me some other design for that?

Comment: Actually, it's called 'Allowed value table', you know. There is an opinion that it's not good to combine because this table wil contain the info of a different kind, but from my point of view (dynamically created queries, frontends and scripting functions) there are more 'pros' than 'cons'. And, like in the example, the info stored has just the same structure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris,_Texas_(film)

Comment: Changed 'country' to 'language' so it would not confuse. Nice movie, btw! 